# Python search for multiple values and show with boundaries

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to allow the user to do this:

Lets say initially the text says:

```
"hello world hello earth"
```

when the user searches for "hello" it should display:

```
|hello| world |hello| earth
```

here's what I have:

```
m = re.compile(pattern)
i =0
match = False
while i < len(self.fcontent):
    content = " ".join(self.fcontent[i])
    i = i + 1;
    for find in m.finditer(content):    
        print i,"\t"+content[:find.start()]+"|"+content[find.start():find.end()]+"|"+content[find.end():]
        match = True
        pr = raw_input( "(n)ext, (p)revious, (q)uit or (r)estart? ")
        if (pr == 'q'):
            break
        elif (pr == 'p'):
            i = i -  2
        elif (pr == 'r'):
            i = 0
if match is False:
    print "No matches in the file!"
```

where :

```
pattern = user specified pattern
fcontent = contents of a file read in and stored as array of words and lines e.g:
[['line','1'],['line','2','here'],['line','3']]
```

however it prints

```
|hello| world hello earth
hello world |hello| earth
```

how can i merge the two lines to be displayed as one? 
Thanks

**Edit**:

This a part of a larger search function where the pattern..in this case the word "hello" is passed from the user, so I have to use regex search/match/finditer to find the pattern. The replace and other methods sadly won't work because the user can choose to search for "[0-9]$" and that would mean to put the ending number between |'s

Comment: Can you tell us more about the target? Could it ever be part (ie a substring) of another word? Or will it be a word on its own? Could we get more sample data (input/output pairs) to show the various constraints?

Comment: ...And as far as troubleshooting your code, what is `fcontent`? What is `m`?

Comment: It should be a word on its own

Comment: fcontent is just the array that has the lines I am searching from...its the content of the file i read in. Updating the code for m...sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, going back to original solution since OP confirmed that word would stand on its own (ie not be a substring of another word).

```
target = 'hello'
line = 'hello world hello earth'
rep_target = '|{}|'.format(target)

line = line.replace(target, rep_target)
```

yields:

```
|hello| world |hello| earth
```

Comment: You may want to pad `target` with spaces to prevent it from matching parts of other words.

Comment: I was just updating my answer for that :)

Comment: @Downvoter .. why the downvote? Not helpful or constructive without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just doing that, use `str.replace`.

```
print self.content.replace(m.find, "|%s|" % m.find)
```

Comment: What if the user looks for "earth" and the text is "a buried treasure was unearthed yesterday"?  You'd get "a buried treasure was un|earth|ed yesterday".  It's not clear whether that's what the OP is after or not.. depends on whether the search is meant to highlight words or substrings, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, if the OP has only words in mind, `re.sub` or `str.split` and a genexp would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regexp as follows:

```
import re
src = "hello world hello earth"
dst = re.sub('hello', '|hello|', src)
print dst
```

or use string replace:

```
dst = src.replace('hello', '|hello|')
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out based on your example, using str.replace is the easiest. If more complex criteria is required, then you can adapt the following...

```
import re

def highlight(string, words, boundary='|'):
    if isinstance(words, basestring):
        words = [words]
    rs = '({})'.format(boundary.join(sorted(map(re.escape, words), key=len, reverse=True)))
    return re.sub(rs, lambda L: '{0}{1}{0}'.format(boundary, L.group(1)), string)
```