# Python search for specific word and show them with boundaries in a intermittent word sequence

Tags: python, regex

I have a Chinese sentence with POS tags and have an itemset associated with it.

### Sentence

```
'另外/c ，/wd 宝来/nz 所/usuo 具有/v 的/ude1 麦弗逊式/n ，/wd 螺旋/n 弹簧/n ，/wd 筒式/n 减振器/n ，/wd 带/v 稳定杆/nz //w 纵向/n 托臂式/n ，/wd 螺旋/n 弹簧/n ，/wd 筒式/n 减振器/n ，/wd 带/v 稳定杆/nz 悬挂/n 系统/n 明显/ad 比/p 思域/nz 的/ude1 麦弗逊式/n 独立/ad 悬架/nz 、/wn 双横臂式/n 独立/ad 悬架/nz 系统/n 的/ude1 乘坐/v 舒适性/n （/wkz 空间/n 不够/a ）/wky 更/d 好/a ！/wt'
```

### Itemset

```
['宝来', '麦弗逊式', '螺旋弹簧', '筒式减振器', '杆/纵向托臂式', '螺旋弹簧', '筒式减振器', '悬挂系统', '比', '思域', '麦弗逊式', '悬架系统', '乘坐舒适性', '更好']
```

### Desired Result

```
'另外/c ，/wd [宝来/nz] 所/usuo 具有/v 的/ude1 [麦弗逊式/n] ，/wd [螺旋/n 弹簧/n] ，/wd [筒式/n 减振器/n] ，/wd 带/v 稳定 [杆/nz //w 纵向/n 托臂式/n] ，/wd [螺旋/n 弹簧/n] ，/wd [筒式/n 减振器/n] ，/wd 带/v 稳定杆/nz [悬挂/n 系统/n] 明显/ad [比/p] [思域/nz] 的/ude1 [麦弗逊式/n] 独立/ad 悬架/nz 、/wn 双横臂式/n 独立/ad [悬架/nz 系统/n] 的/ude1 [乘坐/v 舒适性/n] （/wkz 空间/n 不够/a ）/wky [更/d 好/a] ！/wt'
```

I want to encompass one or some word/tag tokens in the sentence with a bracket, but as the sentence already has been POS-tagged, I can't make use of re.sub or similar ways suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711045/python-search-for-multiple-values-and-show-with-boundaries) . Getting it more burdensome is that the boundary of an item(杆/纵向托臂式) is NOT aligned with token's boundary.

Please comment solutions or introduce any algorithm related to this problem. Thanks.