# Python Search the specific word sequence from the pos sequence and highlight it

Tags: python, regex

Let's say we have a sentence like this,

```
 string = "He/PRP has/VBZ some/DT well/RB made/VBN clothes/NNS made/VBN by/IN a/DT Italian/JJ American/JJ tailor/NN in/IN the/DT Italian/JJ club/NN ./."
```

and I have a list of compound words to be highlighted.

```
target = ['He', 'wellmade', 'ItalianAmerican']
```

and I want to get the result looks like below.

```
"[He/PRP] has/VBZ some/DT [well/RB made/VBN] clothes/NNS made/VBN by/IN a/DT [Italian/JJ American/JJ] tailor/NN in/IN the/DT Italian/JJ club/NN ./."
```

It is assumed that the length of each target item is **the same or longer** than the corresponding tokens in a sentence. I think I should first spot the the span that corresponds to target items, and then insert the brackets, but I can't implement it into a code. Please give me some hint. thanks!

Comment: Why your targets are not represented in the string? Can you just target "Italian" for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import re
re.sub(r'((?:He|well.*?made|Italian.*?American).*?)(\s)', r'[\1]\2', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with 'He', problems begin with 'wellmade', as it is a compound word that is split in the input string, even with suffixes appended. I'd suggest turning your `target` items into regex patterns with optional groups: `(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?` should be inserted after each letter but the last, and `(?:\/[A-Z]+)?` after the last letter.

Have a look at a sample regex for `ItalianAmerican`:

`I(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?t(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?a(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?l(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?i(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?a(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?n(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?A(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?m(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?e(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?r(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?i(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?c(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?a(?:\/[A-Z]+\s*|\s)?n(?:\/[A-Z]+)?`

Have a look at the [demo example](https://regex101.com/r/kT4dX4/1).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful example. Actually, It was a sub-question of [my another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102400/python-search-for-specific-word-and-show-them-with-boundaries-in-a-intermittent). It would much more complex to be implemented with that. Thank you for a lesson anyway!